# Find GitHub Actions still using Node 12 inside an Org's repos

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to find which repos in my GitHub Org have workflows which still use Node 12.

I know that I can go to the latest run for each workflow and see if there is a warning from GitHub, however we have a lot of repos with a lot of workflows and I'm hoping there is a way to collect this list without manually going through all our repos.

I tried looking in the audit log for the org, but I didn't find anything in the logs that looked like it could tell me which workflows were showing warnings. I also did not see a way in either the new or old search to check for these warnings.

Comment: That would be pretty complex, because if you use a third-party action that uses an old node version, you'd get that warning, too. You could write tooling that retrieves all workflow files, extracts the `uses` steps, and then retrieves the `action.yml` files from those repos...

Comment: I think what @BenjaminW. is suggesting is about the best you can get. Another item to add to your toolbelt is to add dependabot for updating actions. At the very least you would get PRs to keep your actions up to date on their latest versions. https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/keeping-your-actions-up-to-date-with-dependabot

Comment: Actually looks like you might be able to use the SBOM tooling at https://github.com/org/repo/network/dependencies to see the actions in a .json file. https://github.blog/2023-03-28-introducing-self-service-sboms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may automate this using the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/), its [annotations extension](https://github.com/swfz/gh-annotations), and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

See this [article](https://dev.to/swfz/i-made-a-cli-extension-to-get-the-annotation-list-of-github-actions-5abm) on this [annotations extension](https://github.com/swfz/gh-annotations) for its detailed usage.

After setting up `gh`, its annotations extension, and `jq`, it should be something like this in `bash`:

```bash
NODEJS12_DEPRECATION_MSG="Node.js 12 actions are deprecated."

ORG="<YOUR-ORG-HERE>"
REPOS="$(gh repo list "$ORG" --json name --jq '.[] | join("")')"

for REPO in $REPOS; do
    echo -n "$ORG/$REPO "
    ANNOTATIONS_JSON="$(gh annotations --repo "$ORG/$REPO" -json | jq -c '.')"
    if [[ $ANNOTATIONS_JSON != "null" ]]; then
        MESSAGE="$(jq '.[0].message' <<< "$ANNOTATIONS_JSON")"
        if grep "$NODEJS12_DEPRECATION_MSG" <<< "$MESSAGE"; then
            echo "[NOT OK] [DEPRECATION WARNING FOUND]"
        else
            echo "[OK] [OTHER ANNOTATIONS FOUND]"
        fi
        jq '.' <<< "$ANNOTATIONS_JSON"
        echo "---"
    else
        echo "[OK] [NO ANNOTATIONS FOUND]"
    fi
done
```

You may further refine this according to your exact use case.